# Android - Which fragment method constantly calls when fragment is running?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know which method constantly calls when fragment is running? Is it onResume(). I have a condition (if statement), i want that the fragment constantly checks the condition and if it is true do the following task that i want to do.
For example:

```
     if (heartdata >= 100 || bloodata >= 120 || tempdata >= 100)
    {
       sendMessage();
    }
```

Where should i put this IF statement so that the android fragment/app constantly checks the condition and call the sendMessage();
i put the code in onCreate() it didn't worked i also put that in onCreateView() but didn't worked please tell me where to put this code..

Comment: You should not do this task on mainUi thread

Comment: where to put this code then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a `TimerTask` and schedule it at regular intervals using `Timer` because `Fragment` Life cycle methods won't be called repeatedly while `fragment` is stable and running. Paste below code in `onViewCreated` method of your `fragment`

**Example**

```
     Timer timer = new Timer(); //Global declaration
     public void onViewCreated(..){
     ...
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { 
                @Override
                public void run() {
                     if (heartdata >= 100 || bloodata >= 120 || tempdata >= 100)
                      {
                        sendMessage();
                      }
                }
            },60 * 1000); // Which will run for every 60 seconds
      ...
      }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        timer.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: My Pleasure :) Glad I could help !

Comment: Would you please tell me how to stop timer task thread when fragment is destroyed or out of focus

Comment: @ZohaibZJ I have edited the answer to meet your needs, hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you.. Timer task will automatically call when i go back to fragment? because i put the above code in onViewCreated();

Comment: Yep :) you can check by debugging !

Answer (score 0):

You can view the `Fragment` life-cycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Basically there is no method that "constantly checks". For example the method `onResume()` is called only when a the fragment is resumed.

If you want to constantly check if a condition is satisfied, i'd suggest creating a background thread and running the code you stated above inside that thread. Once the condition is met, send your message.

Comment: please give me sample code so that i can understand it easily

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html just put your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean named `isRunning`
In `onResume` set `isRunning` to true and in `onPause` set it to false.
Or use `onStart` and `inStop` thatever you want.

And then your while statement:
`while(isRunning)` and `do` whatever you want there...

However I am not really sure if this is good for performance

P.S.: Use `while` or maybe `for` if you want to do aciton repeatedly.. not `if`... `if` is kind of check

Answer (score 0):

I think for this purpose you should use a new Thread in which you continuously checking that condition and when that condition is reached give callback to fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will check every 1SEC

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(getActivity()!=null) {
                mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
            }else{
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                return;
            }
            //Your check code will here
        }
    };
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mHandler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }
}
```